# The markup in the document following the root element must be well informed.How to cure this error?

Tags: android, xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <menu>
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/point_latitude"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="25dip"
        android:layout_marginRight="25dip"
    />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/point_longitude"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="25dip"
        android:layout_marginRight="25dip"
    />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/find_coordinates_button"
        android:text="Find Coordinates"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/save_point_button"
        android:text="Save Point"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    />

   </LinearLayout>
 </menu>
```

This error is shown on the second line (`<menu>`)
Please suggest a fix to this problem. I have moved here and there and have been told that it should be properly closed by `</menu>`, but still it shows me an error.

Comment: Can we get the full error text?

Comment: Menus don't hold View-based layouts. What are you trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

well I guess it says `"must be well formed"` and not *"well informed"* :) Placing `Views` inside a menu tag is not possible. Please consult this Google documentation about creating a menu in xml and this will solve your problem: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/menu-resource.html